# Count number of substrings of a given strings which are anagrams

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension

I need to find anagrams of all substrings of a given string. I found all possible substrings for the given string using the following code:

```
def anagrams(string):
    # abba
    subs = [string[i:j+1] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i, len(string))]
    # ['a', 'ab', 'abb', 'abba', 'b', 'bb', 'bba', 'b', 'ba', 'a']
```

I want to find substrings of equal length from this list and if they are anagrams. Any thoughts?

Comment: And what is the given string?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Finding substrings of the same length, or testing whether two strings are anagrams of each other?

Comment: @yatu It's apparently `abba`.

Comment: @Barmar apparently, both.

Comment: Could yo be more specific about the expected output? You want to output the substrings of the input string that are anagrams of each other?

Comment: ` substrings of equal lengths from this list and if they are anagrams`, what do you consider an anagram here?

Comment: @DanielMesejo the expected output is (ab, ba), (a, a), (b, b), (abb, bba) which are of equal lengths and anagrams too.

Answer (score 2):

If two strings are anagrams they must have the same length, you can just test them directly with a simple nested `for` loop.

To check if two strings are anagrams, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) comes in handy: it counts the occurrences of every distinct element in an iterable, so two strings `si` and `sj` are anagrams if and only if `Counter(si) == Counter(sj)`.

```
from collections import Counter

def anagrams(string):
    subs = [string[i:j+1] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i, len(string))]
    counters = list(map(Counter, subs))
    total = 0

    for i, ci in enumerate(counters):
        for j, cj in enumerate(counters):
            if i != j and ci == cj:
                total += 1

    return total
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken anagrams can have any order of the letters for instance 'abc' is an anagram of 'acb'

Comment: @DanielMesejo whoops, totally right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As in @MarcoBonelli answer you could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a representation of a string that will be equal if and only if the strings are anagrams of each other, for example:

```
'bba' -> ('b', 2), ('a', 1)
'abb' -> ('b', 2), ('a', 1)
```

Instead of doing a nested for loop and check every pair, you could use a dictionary to group strings with the same Counter representation and use a single loop:

```
from collections import Counter


def anagrams(string):
    subs = [string[i:j+1] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i, len(string))]

    anagrams = {}
    for si in subs:
        key = frozenset(Counter(si).items())
        anagrams.setdefault(key, []).append(si)

    # only want the groups with more than one element
    return list(value for value in anagrams.values() if len(value) > 1)


result = anagrams('abba')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['abb', 'bba'], ['b', 'b'], ['ab', 'ba'], ['a', 'a']]
```

In the output the sub-list corresponds to the groups of strings that are anagrams of each other. To use the Counter in a dictionary you have to convert the items to a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Finally this approach complexity is *O(n)* where *n* is the number of substrings.